# How can I restrict a dateInput in R to specific months?

Tags: r, date, shiny

I want to implement a Shiny app that has a dateInput, but I want to restrict the user to select a range of months (e.g. January - June) regardless the year. Is there any possible way?

Comment: yes! a quick google would have been given you that http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateRangeInput.html

Comment: I have searched for it trust me and the link above is not what I want to implement. It restricts the dateInput based on the format "dd-mm-yyyy" and I want something like "dd-mm" only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, here you go:

```
test_dt <- seq(as.Date('2015-01-01'), as.Date('2015-12-31'), by = "month")
as.character(test_dt, format = "%B")

[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

Comment: At this example you specify the year and I dont want that. I want the dateInput to have all the years available but only a month restriction.

Comment: For dates, you actually need to specify a year (the format is `as.Date('1970-01-01', format = '%Y-%m-%d')`, but when I do `as.character`, it turns the data into a character vector. This doesn't have any year information. For the scenario you describe, I think this should probably do it, and it may be a case when using `factor` is more appropriate.

Comment: Alex thanks for the updates. The fact is that I want to give the user of the app the possibilty to select, from the dataInput, dates that are of any year and day but the months available must be a sub set of the year. So in the dataInput I have to enter a start, an end, a min and a max. is there another solurion for dates maybe or a possible workaround with the default library?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may realize this function through `validate... need` construction, where you can check that months entered by user are within required range. You can read more here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/validate.html

Comment: That's a good idea! I will try something else first that came in mind. If it doesn't work I will try it! I will update the post eith the details.